# I have one application some firewalls allowing my IP, Ports and proxies but some firewalls blocking my application

Tags: c++, windows, firewall

I have one application  some firewalls allowing my ip, ports and proxies but some firewalls  blocking my application any help? all third party firewall should allow my application how to allow?

Comment: It's not possible to do on your end, unless your app is influential enough that firewall providers will reach out to you to make sure your app works with their firewall. The only thing you can do is to make sure your users are notified that your app requires a connection and they need to allow it in their firewall. And try to use standard protocols, which are unlikely to be blocked.

Comment: What ports and protocols does your application uses? Please edit your question and add all incoming and outgoing ports the protocol (TCP/UDP) + the used application level protocol (e.g. HTTP(S)).